# Backoff algorithm on iOS

Tags: ios, sockets

Is there any advantage of having a backoff algorithm for TCP socket reconnections on iOS? For example, would a maximum delay of 5 seconds vs 30 seconds have a noticeable impact on battery usage? It seems to me that the backoff algorithm is mainly useful to avoid a DOS on the server if it is temporarily unable to handle the load. The benefits from a client perspective don't seem obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Backoff algorithms (exponential backoffs) help client also handle any ongoing congestion at the server. If the server is busy after the client waits for T seconds, then the next time, it has more chance of reaching the server, if it tried after 2T seconds. Here is a link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff

Secondly, with TCP, it is also possible that the queue of pending connections at the server might be full and in that case, TCP server will implicitly drop the SYN packet (in Linux/Unix).  Having a backoff allows the client enough time so that the application at TCP server can dequeue those pending connections (by calling accept()) and thereby create space in the queue for the client doing backoff.